# Multi Font Warning: preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds in Next JS 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I created Typescript file in nextjs and added a Multi Local Font in file. everything is good but i get warning preloaded in console.

i added a font typescript file in custom file like this:

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";

const sloth = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./Sloth-Light.ttf",
      weight: "300",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./Sloth-Regular.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./Sloth-SemiBold.ttf",
      weight: "600",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./SLOTH BOLD.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./Sloth Extrabold.ttf",
      weight: "800",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  variable: "--sloth-font",
});

export default sloth;
```

and set in _app.tsx like this:

```
import sloth from "@/assets/fonts/Sloth/fontSloth";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "@/components/Common/base.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <main className={sloth.className}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

i created this file from this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#local-fonts

but i get warning in console like this:
`The resource at “http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/14d02ffbd50785a8-s.p.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. localhost:3000 The resource at “http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/d59ccbe0e6984999-s.p.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. localhost:3000 The resource at “http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/bec92e8079a45897-s.p.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. localhost:3000 The resource at “http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/608ed55882545917-s.p.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. localhost:3000 The resource at “http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/ab546308a292d6f2-s.p.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.`

how to fix it?